# Querying a xml in sql server 2008

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, xquery

I wan t to upload the xml data to the sql table. I am passing the xml data from .net(c#)(Working fine)

code:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BookDetails_Insert] (@xml xml)

 AS
 insert into BookDetails (Pages,Descriptions) 
  SELECT 
    ParamValues.PLName.value('.','int'),
    ParamValues.PLDEscr.value('.','text')
FROM 
    @xml.nodes('/booksdetail/Pages') as ParamValues(PLName)
            @xml.nodes('/booksdetail/Description') as ParamValues(PLName, PLDEscr)
```

xml Code:

```
  <booksdetail>
  <isbn_13>70100048</isbn_13> 
  <isbn_10>00048B</isbn_10> 
  <Image_URL>http://www.thenet.com/Book/large/00/701001048.jpg</Image_URL> 
  <title>QUICK AND FLUPKE</title> 
  <Description>QUICK AND FLUPKE </Description> 
  </booksdetail>
  <booksdetail>...</booksdetail>
```

Problem: It is not doing anything on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample xml does not have a `Pages` node. This means that when the `FROM` clause is computed, a cross join is formed between a list of zero rows and a list of one row. The resulting product has no rows, so there is nothing `SELECT`ed, so nothing is `INSERT`ed.

If you actually want to insert one row into `BookDetails` for each `booksdetail` node in the incoming xml, you should do *something like*

```
SELECT 
    ParamValues.PL.value('Pages[1]','int'),
    CAST(ParamValues.PLr.value('Description[1]','varchar(max)') AS text)
FROM 
    @xml.nodes('/booksdetail') as ParamValues(PL)
```

That is, shred the incoming xml into `booksdetail` nodes, and pull out each of the `.value`s you want from these rows.