# Timeout expired. Problem in Exporting xml to sql server 2008 data table - .net

Tags: .net, xml, sql-server-2008, timeout, xml-database

I am exporting xml data to sql server 2008 database.

.net code: [How to pass XML from C# to a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600091/how-to-pass-xml-from-c-to-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2008)

Query to insert: [Querying a xml in sql server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606649/querying-a-xml-in-sql-server-2008)

Everthing is working fine if the file size is small. Now the xml file size is above 5mb. It showing timeout error. How to resolve this.

Error: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated.

Geetha.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the timeout of the command, for example:

```
command.CommandTimeout = 3600;
```

The value is measured in seconds.

However, you may need to alter the XML import SQL.  You can often get better performance by using the `OPENXML` clause instead of the `nodes` XML data type method.  See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx) for information and examples about `OPENXML`.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `SqlBulkCopy Class`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

this will be a better option if the size of data is more.it will insert GBs of data in fraction of seconds.

For solving your error try this: [SqlCommand.CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx)